# Dependency property binding Issue WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dependency-properties

Kindly let me know what I am doing wrong

XAML of `UserControl` where I use my child `UserControl` with dependency property

ComboBox `SelectedItem` will Update `SelectedEmployee`,

This `SelectedEmployee` is further Binded with My child Control `CardView:uEmployeeCard` ViewModel Property

```
<ComboBox  Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
           Style="{StaticResource UiComboBox}"
           ItemsSource="{Binding TB_EMPLOYEEList}"
           SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedEmployee,
                          Mode=TwoWay,
                          UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
           SelectedValuePath="ID"
           SelectedValue="{Binding CurrentTB_RECIEPT.REFRENCEID}"
           ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ComboEmployeeTemplate}"/>

<CardView:uEmployeeCard  ViewModel="{Binding Path=SelectedEmployee}"
                         Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
                         Grid.RowSpan="3" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
```

---

**Dependency Property Code, Code Behind file of uEmployeeCard:**

```
public  uEmployeeCard()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = this;
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty ViewModelProperty = 
    DependencyProperty.Register("ViewModel",
        typeof(TB_EMPLOYEE),
        typeof(uEmployeeCard), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata
            {
                BindsTwoWayByDefault = true,
                DefaultUpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged
            });

[Bindable(true)]
public  TB_EMPLOYEE ViewModel
{
    get { return (TB_EMPLOYEE)GetValue(ViewModelProperty); } //do NOT modify anything in here
    set { SetValue(ViewModelProperty, value);  } //...or here
}
```

---

**Xaml File of uEmployeeCard (Child User Control):**

```
<StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal">
    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource UiTextBlock}"
               Text="{Binding Path=ViewModel.TITLE}"/>
    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource UiTextBlock}"
               Text="{Binding Path=ViewModel.FIRSTNAME}"/>
    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource UiTextBlock}"
               Text="{Binding Path=ViewModel.FIRSTNAME}"/>
</StackPanel>
<StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Vertical" Grid.RowSpan="2">
    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource UiTextBlock}"
               Text="{Binding Path=ViewModel.NATNO}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

---

I put breakpoint to check whether the dependency property get affected on update from ComboBox on parent user control. but not...

Comment: WPF usually bypasses the CLR wrappers for a dependency property, hence your getter or setter isn't called. See here for an explanation: [XAML Loading and Dependency Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613563.aspx).

Comment: Yes you are right, but as you see I put no logic there. Beside that I cross checked my code but unable to find what am I missing so that my chilcontrols field not get populated once I make changes at My parent control to which combobox selecteditem child control is binded.

Comment: Have you already tried to edit the PropertyBinding in the ChildControl with the following: "Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged"? You could also try to give your ComboBox a Name, and bind your ChildControl to ViewModel="{Binding ElementName=NamedComboBox, Path=SelectedItem}"

Comment: @BastiOnWpf Yes dear you code work, Now its working thanks a lot. bro... I want to mark your comment as answer. so that it may help others too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you already tried to edit the `PropertyBinding` in the `ChildControl` with the following:

```
"Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged"
```

You could also try to give your `ComboBox` a name and bind your `ChildControl` to it:

```
ViewModel="{Binding ElementName=NamedComboBox, Path=SelectedItem}"
```